# Media is not showing on post page

Tags: custom-post-types, images, theme-options, read-more, post-content

I'm building a wordpress website based on the theme "Bulk Shop".

Most of the content will be added as "post" and will be categorized into "next show", "last show", "music", "videos", etc.

https://boba-music.com/category/music/

https://boba-music.com/category/videos/

https://boba-music.com/category/next-show/

Here are all posts collected (post page):
https://boba-music.com/news/

My problem is, only title, text and the "read more" is shown on the category post pages, but pictures, soundcloud audio, youtube videos are not shown. Only if I click on read more.

I want to show the full content, e.g. all content until I add the "read more tag".

What do I do wrong or what do I need to change to see all the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either choose a theme that already shows full posts on Categories by default, or you can create a child theme:

1. Create a new folder under `/wp-content/themes/` - the name is up to you, but for simplicity's sake, you may just want to call it themename-child. So if you're using the "twentysixteen" theme, call your folder `twentysixteen-child`.
2. Create a file called `style.css` in your folder. It will just need a couple of comments so WP recognizes your child theme, no actual styles are needed. You can name it anything you like (again, I suggest calling it a child so it's obvious) - the only requirement is "template" has to be the parent theme's folder. So for "twentysixteen":

`/*
Theme Name: WPSE custom child theme
Template: twentysixteen
*/`

3. Look through the theme files to find the archive. Most themes have a file called `category.php` but if that doesn't exist you may need `archive.php`. You are looking for a call to `the_excerpt()` which, if it is not in `category.php` or `archive.php`, may be in a template part such as `archive-content.php` - that would be called as `get_template_part()` inside of `archive.php` or `content.php`. Once you identify which one controls your categories - which you can find by replacing `the_excerpt()` with `the_content()` temporarily - copy that whole file into your child theme. Then, wherever inside that file there is a call to `the_excerpt()` just replace that with `the_content()` to display the full content instead of an excerpt. Make sure to change the parent theme file back - you don't want to edit parent theme files directly, as when they update, your changes are overwritten. By making all of your changes through a child theme, your changes will remain in effect.

Comment: Thank you so much Elaine! 
You just teached me to do my very first child theme, that's so awesome! :D
Everything worked out, see on www.boba-music.com
I'm so thankful for your help! <3
Stef